# CAF Receiver - removeSupportedMediaCommands - Understanding of Usage

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Hello fellow Chromecast devs!
I've got a Chromecast question, on expectation of a method in the PlayerManager (at the bottom).
I have a Chromecast receiver that is provided both VOD and Live video load requests.
I want to remove seek, play/pause controls from the UI on both the Sender and Receiver devices connected to the cast session during Live video playback, and toggle them back on when VOD content is resumed.

- Is there a way to do this UI switching for sender/receiver controls from the Receiver code only, so our sender teams aren't impacted?  Or do we need to collaborate control change requests in some other way, like custom messages?

**Things we've tried:**

- Using `setSupportedMediaCommands` , `addSupportedMediaCommands`, and `removeSupportedMediaCommands`, with broadcasting flag enabled, disabled, set in the LoadRequest interceptor. (Varied results, sometimes the Android Sender removes controls, sometimes not.  iOS almost consistently does not.)
- Removing buttons via [slot configuration](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/optimize-smart-displays#customize_ui_control_button_layout) (removes the buttons on Receiver only, makes sense)
- Enforcing media commands in the MEDIA_STATUS interceptor using the supportedMediaCommands prop (removes the buttons on Receiver only, also makes sense)

**Things we would like:**

- My hope is that there is a solution or workflow that would allow us to control the Receiver controls, and mini-controller/expanded-controller on the Sender devices all at once, without the need for custom messages or burdening our Sender device teams.

Is this possible?  Should the `removeSupportedMediaCommands` method also remove controls from any Senders, and it just isn't working in our workflow?  Is there a certain time (after session start) that this method needs to be called by to always work?  The docs aren't giving me much help with how this method interacts with the Senders.

Thanks!